# How to add link to column table to sort using spring-jpa?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I'm using the code from this repository to implement my table + paginator in Springboot and works great with some minor modifications.

https://github.com/mtiger2k/pageableSpringBootDataJPA

I need just one more thing. Add a link to every column to sort it.

I have found a suggestion:

```
<td th:href="@{/product(sort=(${page?.sort?.getOrderFor('id')?.ascending} ? 'id,desc' : 'id,asc'))}" th:text="${product.id}">Id</td>
```

So I understand that using the info in:
**org.springframework.data.domain.Page;**, I have all the information, but I'm not be able to change it so it works in my case.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can accept the sort attributes as params:

```
/products?page=1&size=50&sortBy=name&sortDirection=ASC
```

And in the controller it should be as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/products", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String list(Model model,@RequestParam int page,@RequestParam int size, @RequestParam String sortBy,@RequestParam Sort.Direction sortDirection){
       Pageable page = new PageRequest(page, size, sortDirection, sortBy);
      Page<Product> productPage = productService.findAll(page);
      //code
}
```

Hoping that your requirement is to enable user sort by different fields in Product, `sortBy` will hold the name of the field in class `Product` over which you need to sort.